# Kivy - Add an icon to tab buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, icons, kivy

I am using a TabbedPanel in Kivy, it works perfectly well, but I would like to customize the tab buttons a bit and add a icon next to the text.

Right now I have something like this :
[image: Current tab]

And I would like something like that :
[image: Tab with icons]

My kv file is as follows :

```
<KivyMasterPanel>
    do_default_tab: False
    id: MasterPanel
    tab_width: self.size[0]/len(self.tab_list)

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab_A
        text: 'A'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab_B
        text: 'B'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab_C
        text: 'C'
```

Is there something I can use instead of TabbedPannelItem.text to put a BoxLayout or something inside. If possible I would like to be able to create my tabs using a kv file, but if it is not possible, no problem.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom `TabbedPanelItem`, where you'll add image background with `Rectangle`

```
<TPI@TabbedPanelItem>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: <your_img>
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

and use the custom one instead of `TabbedPanelItem` in your `KivyMasterPanel`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Using Rectangle's size and pos properties, it is possible to position the icon easily in the tab

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works. However, I can't access the text position. When the window is being resized, at some point the thumbnail will be on top of the text. Do you know of a way to put a Layout inside the tab? This way I would be able to position the thumb way relative to the text

Comment: @ClementPuech I think your problem is that you use `pos: self.pos[0] + <number>, ...` and not something flexible. You can fix it with positioning `Rectangle` relatively(`pos: self.pos[0] + 0.3*self.size[0], self.pos[1]`) or something in similar way. Positioning the text manually would be possible maybe with [behavior](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.ToggleButtonBehavior) and custom `TabbedPanelHeader` which uses `TabbedPanelItem` as a class it inherits from. The first option is the best for you if you don't want to cripple it. ^^

Comment: I did not understand how to use that custom one. 
How does that <KivyMasterPanel> look like after that change?